# Лошадь и конь - синонимы?

Tags: этимология, синонимы

Я как большой любитель лошадей и человек, кое-что в них понимающий, всегда поправляю тех, кто считает, что лошадь - это существо женского пола, а конь - мужского. Лошадь женского пола называется кобыла, а мужского - жеребец (а кастрированный - мерин). Лошадь и конь же - это синонимы. В украинском языке слова "лошадь" вообще нет, а есть только "кiнь" по отношению к обоим полам. А в русском слово "конь" имеет более поэтический оттенок, то есть старую беспородную клячу уже конем сложно назвать.

Так вот, почему для лошади существует два названия (как, кстати, для собаки, которая еще и пес) и почему "конь - это звучит гордо"?

Comment: Я читал,  что  конь  и  мерин - синонимы.

Comment: Старую,  беспородную  клячу  можно  назвать  конягой.

Comment: @bernard, из википедии: "среди коневодов и спортсменов-конников в настоящее время встречается использование слова «конь» вместо «мерин»". Т.е. да, такая тенденция есть (если википедия не врёт), но сформировалась она в последнее время.

Comment: @Sasha - интересно, а вместо какорго слова тогда употреблен термин "синоним"? Тут не во времени дело, ав том, что такое употребление совершенно не делает коня *синонимом* мерина. Ну тенденция, ну у конников... Слабая, узкопрофессиональная, разговорная... Это даже если верить википедии (что вообще-то тоже надо делать с осторожностью).

Comment: @behemothus, «*интересно, а вместо какорго слова тогда употреблен термин "синоним"?*» — не понял смысл вопроса. «*Такое употребление совершенно не делает коня синонимом мерина*» — AFAIK, чтобы слова были [частичными синонимами](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/частичный_синоним), не обязательно полное совпадение всех значений, может быть словоА(VII)=словоБ(III).

Comment: @Sasha Вот и я не понял, зачем считать синонимами узкое эмфатическое употребление. Если я соседского Вовку обозвал дураком, это что ж получится, что Вовка - (частичный) синоним дурака? Кстати, у Бернарда, который эту псевдо-инфу вбросил, вообще ни о какой **частичности** даже и речи не идет. Или я что-то пропустил?

Comment: @Sasha *может быть словоА(VII)=словоБ(III)* Может. Но тут надо точно выражаться, чтобы не было двусмысленности. **Конь - это *гипероним* мерина**. Это в корне меняет понимание.

Comment: @behemothus, дело в том, что — не знаю правда это или нет, но — по сети ходит информация, что в некоторых (узкопрофессиональных) кругах слово «конь» употребляют как синоним к слову «мерин». Т.е. не гипероним, а именно синоним. Типа, **конь**: (1) лошадь, как правило мужского пола; (2) гимнастический снаряд; (3) *проф. сленг* мерин, т.е. гипоним для первого значения; (4) и пр.

Comment: @Sasha Мы по кругу ходим. В каком значении вы употребили слово синоним? Конь и лошадь - ***гиперонимы*** к мерину, жеребенку, жеребцу, кобыле. Не "проф.", а вообще.  Почему синоним-то?

Comment: @behemothus, конь(1) -- гипероним к мерин, конь(3) -- синоним.

Comment: @Sasha мне не интересно (3). Когда Вы поддакнули Бернарду, ни о каком (3) речь не шло.  (3) - Узкое специальное и эмфатическое. И никому не будет интересно, когда он прочитает, что "Конь - синоним мерина". Хоть стой - хоть падай.

Comment: Все. Больше тут обсуждать нечего.

Comment: @behemothus, Вам неинтересно, мне интересно. Бернард как раз и сообщил о том, что существует (3). По-моему, всевозможные специфические и узкие значения слов «конь» и «лошадь» имеют непосредственное отношение к данному вопросу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для  современного,  особенно  городского  человека  конь  и  лошадь -  синонимы.  Пол  животного  для  него  роли  не  играет.  О  конезаводчиках  и  лошадниках  здесь  речи  нет.  Но  и  раньше,  например  у  Л. Толстого,  кони  и  лошади  обозначают  этих  животных  вообще.  Ни  одно  из  этих  слов  не  звучит  более  гордо,  вернее  не  является  обозначением   более  благородной  особи. У  людей,  чувствительных  к  языку,  может  сложиться  впечатление,  что  лошадь - это  кобыла,  потому  что  оба  слова  женского  рода,  а  конь - это  жеребец,  по  тому  же  признаку.  Чем  эти  слова  действительно  отличаются,  так  это  фонетическим  обликом.  Поэтому  "по  коням!"  звучит  гораздо  лучше,  чем  "по  лошадям!",  конный,  конник  -  всадник,  кавалерист,  рыцарь,  а  это  уже  статус.  Более  звонкое,  песенное  -  кони  и  рядом  не  столь  звучное,  прозаическое  -  лошади.

Answer (score 6):

Поразмышляв над вопросом, составил мнение: *конь - под седлом, лошадь - в оглоблях*. Проверяем у Даля.

> Лошадь - вообще конь; особенно не жеребец и не кобыла, мерин.
> Кляча воду возит, ***лошадь пашет, конь под седлом.***

Примерно так и есть в общедоступных культурологических источниках. На конях скачут всадники, лошадки бегут в упряжке. Определенный процент исключений из этого правила (*чуть помедленнее, кони...*) подтверждает общую его некатегоричность и условность. Поговорка Даля о *кляче, лошади и коне*, между тем, сохранила старинное народное понимание сабжа.

Answer (score 4):

@hanyо, Вы правы по сути, но тут есть уточнение. Вопрос в том, кем и когда эти слова употреблены.

Для специалиста (не простого биотехника) лошадь и конь - синонимы.
Для более точного указания есть жеребец, (под)жеребчик, жеребенок, мерин, кобыла и еще какой-то термин для кобылы-подлетка, не вспомню сейчас, аналогичный "телка" или "яловка" для крупных и рогатых.

Более того, исторически в древнерусском было только слово "конь", означавшее это домашнее животное любого пола.
"Лошадь" появилось позже, видимо из тюркских (хотя есть и другие версии происхождения), первоначально оно означало коня не самых выдающихся качеств и было... мужского рода. 
Со временем стало обозначать коня вообще, и преимущественно - мужского рода.

Но в быту, как это часто бывает, произошло разделение по гендерному признаку. Лошадью стали называть преимущественно кобылу, конем - жеребца (половозрелого).
При этом во множественном числе лошади и кони используются как синонимы.

Повторюсь, использование в разговорном языке "лошадь" и "конь" для указания половой принадлежности вполне допустимо, хотя и вызывает зубовный скрежет любого коневода.

Возвращаясь же к исходному смыслу слова "лошадь", можно понять и то, почему "конь звучит гордо". Потому, что конь - это хороший конь. А лошадь - конь плохонький, или вообще кляча. Видимо где-то на подкорке это представление у наших предков осталось записано и нам передалось даже вопреки современному понимаю значения.

Comment: Лошадью называют животных обоего пола. И, например, в конном спорте, несмотря на название самого спорта, Вы слово "конь" почти не услышите. Нет, я полностью соглашусь с автором, говорить, что лошадь - женского пола, а конь - мужского... мягко скажем, по-детски.

Comment: Я иногда смотрю конный спорт, лошади используются в основном как собирательное, "кони" просто становится ненужным. А так - кобыла, конь или мерин. Ну если комментатор адекватный.  
Но вы меня, боюсь, не совсем поняли. Я сказал, что ***в быту*** лошадь и конь все-таки означают животных разного пола. Несмотря на протесты специалистов, чье мнение я-то как раз весьма уважаю.  
*Сравните: свинья и кабан, хотя по сути это одно и то же, а по науке: хряк, боров, свиноматка, подсвинок и т.д.*

Comment: Интересно,  что  в  "Холстомере"  слова  конь  нет,  только  лошадь  и  конкретные  обозначения - мерин,  кобыла  и  т.п.  Общее  -  лошади.  В  "Кавказском  пленнике  тоже.  Так  что  лошадь  тут  не  "плохонький  конь".  У  Тургенева  в  повести  "Первая  любовь"  ни  одного  слова  конь,  только  лошадь.  А  у  Лескова  в  "Очарованном  страннике"  и  лошади  и  кони,  но  чаще  лошади.  У  Серафимовича  в  "Железном  потоке"  и  кони  и  лошади - примерно  поровну.

Answer (score 1):

Мне известна другая трактовка. Конь - это лошадь в "погонах", т. е. под всадником в боевом строю. В обозе или на хозработах - это лошадь, независимо от того, жеребец/мерин или кобыла.

Такая интерпретация принята у кавалеристов.

Comment: Можете сослаться на источник?

Comment: Конница явно от конского звания происходит